# How can I dismiss my view when I click on cancel?

Tags: swift

When a user clicks on a [cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYDp2.jpg) a new controller shows up.

```
            let form = MobiFormViewController()
            form.documentation = doc
            form.delegate = self
            self.show(form, sender: self)
```

The new controller looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGJNw.png).
I added two ***BarButtonItems***. When the user clicks on ***cancel*** the view should disappear or dismiss.

```
@objc func handleCancel(sender: AnyObject?) {

}
```

I don´t know how to implement it correctly. Should be pretty simple tho but nothing seems to work for me right now. I am new to Swift programming.

Comment: Post your whole code please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `dismiss` for `present`/ `show`

```
self.dismiss(animated:true,completion:nil)
```

If you push it then do

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Comment: Already tried it but it does not work. Controller won´t dismiss. But cancel button is pressed when I check it with print("")

Comment: I figured it out. I had to use ***self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)*** first cause I have a previous with controller  and I want to go back from my current to this one. Thanks anyway for the input!

Answer (score 0):

On your cancel function use `dismiss`

```
@objc func handleCancel(sender: AnyObject?) {
    self.dismiss(animted:true, completion:nil)
}
```

Comment: Already tried it but it does not work. Controller won´t dismiss. But cancel button is pressed when I check it with print("")